# Set AccessibilityService component disabled not working

Tags: android

Please help, I want to disable and enable my class extending `AccessibilityService` programmatically
But does not seems to work.

This is the method I used to try to disable:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, MyAccessService.class),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Of normal, if the class component could be disabled, it shouldn't be listed among the list of Accessibility Apps, but no matter how hard I tried to disable the component nothing changes.

Here is the class in my manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyAccessService" 
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:directBootAware="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
        </service>
```